# How to evaluate elisp --batch after the init file has loaded?

Tags: command-line-arguments

I would like to run code on the command line using the environment created by my own (`early-init.el` & `init.el`).

```sh
emacs --eval '(message "%S" load-path)' --batch
```

... it doesn't show paths added by my custom configuration for example.

How can I run a batch script that contains my user-configuration before executing the script?

Comment: `emacs --batch --load-file /path/to/init.el --load-file /path/to/some/other/file.el ....` I think but the man page should have all the details.

Comment: The issue with this is the file can be in many different locations, so I'd need to duplicate emacs path search order (`_emacs`, `.emacs`, `.emacs.d/init.el`, `.config/emacs/init.el`... etc).

Comment: NickD solution worked for me. Note that it should be `--load`, not `--load-file`, e.g. `emacs --batch --load ~/.emacs.d/init.el --eval '(my-function "my args")'`